# nesting PHP switch and if statements

Tags: php

ok so I decide do a simple switch statement that does mathematical calculations based on the radio values (first is distance and second is time) the user selects.  So distance has 2 radio options and so does time (hour and second). And so I do this:

```
$max1 = 2.7432;
$max2 = 274.32;
$a = $_REQUEST['a'];
$unitA = $_REQUEST['A']; //this gets the 1st selected unit from a radio option user chooses
$unitB = $_REQUEST['B']; //this gets the 2nd selected unit from a radio option user chooses


if((arguments inserted here)) { 
     //do some maths;
}


else {
  //else calculate value based on selected unit
  $selectedUnit= $unitA.$unitB;
  switch ($selectedUnit) {
            case "mileshour":
            echo "SUCCESS"
            break;

            case "milessecond":
            echo "new success";
            break;

            default:
            echo "";
                }
            }
```

This is not working! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(condition)` looks to be invalid. Is that your actual code, or a place-holder?

Comment: What's the condition? What are the errors if any? Did you try an echo in the if condition part? are you making it to the else?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara that's just a place holder.

Comment: How is it behaving? Is it that it is going to the else section , entering the switch case and then executing the default? if that is the case, I would suggest you to remap your HTML values with the values used in the case. There might be a silly mistake involved. As in remap if the first radio is giving miles/<something> and the second gives hour/second. Just a hint if the user selects the second radio in first unit, i.e<something> the case will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code that you are using then the problem (without knowing what error you are receiving or what values are being used) is that the echo statement (echo "SUCCESS") doesn't have a semi-colon terminating the line.

```
$unitA = 'miles';
$unitB = 'hour';
if(false){}
else {
    $selectedUnit = $unitA.$unitB;
    switch($selectedUnit) {
        case 'mileshour':
            echo 'success';
            break;
        case 'milessecond':
            echo 'new success';
            break;
        default:
            echo '';
    }
}
```

If this is the issue I would highly recommend using and IDE like phpstorm which will point out these little problems